# Conditional Validation with Paperclip difficult

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

I have an "item", which goes through a multi-page creation process. Images are uploaded at step five, and I keep track of the steps by using the attribute "complete". When validating whether an image is attached with paperclip, I get problems using the code below:

```
validates_attachment_presence :pic1, :if => Proc.new { |u|  u.complete == "step5"}
```

It seems that I can't access the "complete" attribute, as the active-record object seems to be the paperclip image. Is there a way for me to check at which point in the process I am and validate conditionally?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
validates_attachment_presence :pic1, :if => 'complete == "setp5"?'
```

or

```
validates_attachment_presence :pic1, :if => :is_step5?

def is_step5?
  self.complete == "step5"
end
```