# Rails validate_presence message - how to display?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in the model for Attachments (I'm using Paperclip):

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :attach_file_name, :message => "No file selected"

  has_attached_file :attach
```

Most error messages I get from Rails show up at the top of the screen using this code that's in my layouts:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
<% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Why isn't the validate message showing up?

Thanks for the help!!

UPDATE1

The Attachment gets created from the attachments form _form.html.erb.

This is in the form:

```
<h4>Attachment:</h4>
<%= f.file_field :attach, :label => 'Attachment' %>
```

Comment: We need more information. Where is the Attachment being made that the model should be invalid? How is it being done? Is it being created via AJAX? Because then your page isn't being refreshed and so it wouldn't suddenly show up in your flash errors part.

Comment: I updated my question - hope that helps.

Comment: Open the page on your form, then go to a console and write `gem install debugger`, restart your server with `-d`, write `<% debugger %>` just before `<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>`, fill the form in a way to trigger this flash message and post. It will keep loading without answer nothing, go to your console where you started rails, it will be a prompt. type flash and see what the variable flash has. Then edit your question. - formore debugger commands, use `?`.

Comment: validation errors don't normally show up in flash, unless you put them there, which you didn't mention. In create/update after save/update_attributes returns false you can find the errors in form_variable.errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test the presence of a file from Paperclip, try this:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_attachment_presence :attach, :message => "No file selected"

  has_attached_file :attach
```

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage
- https://makandracards.com/makandra/8043-validate-attachment-presence-using-paperclip
- [Conditional Validation with Paperclip difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595164/conditional-validation-with-paperclip-difficult)

Also, The Rails 3 -way to do `validates` is the following:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :attach, attachment_presence: true, message: 'No file selected!'

  has_attached_file :attach
```